# How can I force my phone to ring an alarm whenever a calendar event starts?

Tags: ios, calendar, alarm

My personal calendar only contains truly important events and I hate missing something when I forget about a notification. Is there an app (or iOS Calendar setting) that would make my phone vibrate and ring an alarm whenever an event starts? I would like it to be able to override silent and Do Not Disturb mode as well to be safe.

This is for iPhone 12 / iOS 15.

Comment: Note: not a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79816/how-can-i-have-calendar-use-an-audible-alarm-for-alerts) as I'm asking about third-party apps primarily, as the default Calendar app is not capable of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the apps on the App Store work well. I tried Calarm or CalAlarm.

What worked instead was creating a Shortcut. You can create an Automation to run the shortcut every day at 1:00am, and it loops through all events on your calendar and makes an alarm for all of them 10 minutes early with the calendar name.

Here’s a link: https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/70c788b054924957b14bf247251d74bf

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Within the Shortcuts application, set scheduled automation at the start of every day. It only works for the 1st event of the day though.

[image]

Comment: Certainly an interesting hack but sadly not for all events

Comment: @JonathanReez Here’s a version that works for all events: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/450019/20803