# notification for a given calendar event to buzz my watch until dismissed?

Tags: notifications, calendar, customization

Per-event calendar notifications appear not to have the option of audible/haptic alerts that persist until dismissed.

Is there a way to create this feature?

As a person who irregularly reads notifications, I'd like to enable selected events to nag me until I acknowledge them so that overlooking key things on my schedule is harder to do.

If this feature exists already, how do I enable it for a given event, esp. for notifications on the watch?

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing this using the built-in Calendar app but there might still be third-party solutions that can do what you want.

Comment: An alarm will sound until cancelled - maybe https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432251/how-can-i-force-my-phone-to-ring-an-alarm-whenever-a-calendar-event-starts might give some hints [I don't use shortcuts & don't have a watch so can't help on that front]

Comment: @Tetsujin - thanks for pointing out that question. The Shortcut it shares goes most of the way, but I've not found a way to run shortcuts on a schedule on an Apple Watch. That remaining need seems too logical not to exist. Perhaps someone has insights/pointers to share about automating Shortcuts on Apple Watch (or even iPhone)? For now I'll add a daily reminder to run the shortcut to check my calendar to set my alarms... or?

Answer (score 0):

There’s no option on a calendar event to “persistently notify you until canceled.”  There are, however, a couple of options that are available to you:

The native Calendar App has the ability to give you a Second Alert (below left) when creating/editing your event.  It can be found under the first “Alert” field.

[image: Apple Watch Calendar First & Second Alert Fields] [image]

However, I use Microsoft Outlook (above right)  and it gives you the ability to snooze an alarm when you are alerted and it will re-notify you again at the event time.

It’s important to note that anything under 15 minutes will *not* get a second notification.  Once I set my notification to 15 minutes or more, it worked as expected.